# Error parsing headers: 'limit request headers fields size' in Nginx

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have deployed my django app with Nginx, I use Jwt Authorization and the token may grow. Initially I was getting `Request Header Or Cookie Too Large` so I googled and find some docs that tells to increase `client_header_buffer_size`, so I did that and set to `client_header_buffer_size 32k` and the error changed to `**Bad Request**  Error parsing headers: 'limit request headers fields size'`

Below is my configs

```
server {
   ......
   client_header_buffer_size 32k
   ......
}
```

Any help will be appreciated guys I have to deploy.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggled for sometimes I found a solution , so the actual problem was I was passing a large jwt token through headers so I had to minimize data that I used to store in my encoded token. That solved my issue

Comment: The solution cannot be to reduce the token's data because it is often impossible.

Comment: If you find impossible to reduce/minimize data you store yourself on the token you can try to encode that token into a much shorter length. Using base64 encoded string will help